# Eclipse Luna stop working in Debian when pop-up open

Tags: eclipse, debian, eclipse-luna

every time I go to the Eclipse-luna IDE and enter a line of code in a class that I created and code assist opens the pop-up with suggestions, stop working the eclipse and only runs again if I kill process and re-run the eclipse.

My OS is the latest stable version of kali (debian based with kernel 3.18.3) x86_64 with open-jdk 1.6 and 1.7 installed by default in the system.

Thank for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure out the problem and solve the same describe below how it was done so to help someone who is having the same problem. To begin i'm using the latest stable version of eclipse-luna downloaded direct with the site or using wget. Open your eclipse.ini file and exactly one row before `--launcher.appendVmargs` enter these two lines below:

`

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

`

and are ready your eclipse'll be already functioning normally in debian remembering that I previously had to change -showsplash to -nosplash.

Below I leave an exact copy of my eclipse.ini remembering that already means tuned.

`

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-nosplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.GTK_version
2
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms80m
-Xmx1024m
```

`

> Thanks for all